# change the size of the image

Tags: graphics, graphics3d

If this is trivial or a duplicate I apologize. I failed to find something.

I have the following code

```
g1 = Graphics3D[{Gray, Specularity[White, 60], Opacity[0.5], 
      Scale[#, {10, 3, 2}], Opacity[1], Scale[#, {.001, 3, 2}]} &@
    Sphere[], Axes -> True];
g2 = Graphics3D[{Thick, {Arrowheads[Medium], 
     Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {10, 0, 0}}], Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 2}}], 
     Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, -3, 0}}]}}];
Rasterize[
 Show[{g1, g2}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, ImagePadding -> None, 
  ImageMargins -> None, 
  PlotRange -> {{-10.1, 10.1}, {-3.1, 3.1}, {-2.1, 2.1}}, 
  ImageSize -> 600, Lighting -> "Neutral"], ImageResolution -> 200]
```

which produces the following figure.
[image]

When I insert this figure in Latex I take something like[image]

As you see there is a lot of space between the caption and the figure. How is it possible to decrease these "white margins"? In order to be more clear see the following figure.
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: So do you want bounding box or not? With `Boxed->False` you can just add `ImageCrop`.

Comment: Sorry. I edited the question.

Comment: Have you tried `Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}`?

Comment: @J.M.: No! Thanks.

Comment: @Kuba. It works also. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If it worked, could you answer your own question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will do what I wanted (thanks to @Kuba and @J.M.)

```
g1 = Graphics3D[{Gray, Specularity[White, 60], Opacity[0.5], 
      Scale[#, {10, 3, 2}], Opacity[1], Scale[#, {.001, 3, 2}]} &@
    Sphere[], Axes -> True];
g2 = Graphics3D[{Thick, {Arrowheads[Medium], 
     Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {10, 0, 0}}], Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 2}}], 
     Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, -3, 0}}]}}];
Rasterize[
 Show[{g1, g2}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, ImagePadding -> None, 
  ImageMargins -> None, 
  PlotRange -> {{-10.1, 10.1}, {-3.1, 3.1}, {-2.1, 2.1}}, 
  ImageSize -> 600, Lighting -> "Neutral", 
  Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}], ImageResolution -> 300]
```

**or**

```
g1 = Graphics3D[{Gray, Specularity[White, 60], Opacity[0.5], 
      Scale[#, {10, 3, 2}], Opacity[1], Scale[#, {.001, 3, 2}]} &@
    Sphere[], Axes -> True];
g2 = Graphics3D[{Thick, {Arrowheads[Medium], 
     Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {10, 0, 0}}], Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 2}}], 
     Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, -3, 0}}]}}];
ImageCrop[
 Rasterize[
  Show[{g1, g2}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, ImagePadding -> None, 
   ImageMargins -> None, 
   PlotRange -> {{-10.1, 10.1}, {-3.1, 3.1}, {-2.1, 2.1}}, 
   ImageSize -> 600, Lighting -> "Neutral", 
   Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}], ImageResolution -> 300]]
```

Both result to the same output.

[image]