# Issue with ImageCrop and Rasterize

Tags: image-processing

This is related to [1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/99861/change-the-size-of-the-image).

I use the following code:

```
 arrowAxes[{axesLength1_, axesLength2_, axesLength3_}, 
  arrowcolor_: Black] := {arrowcolor, Arrowheads[.05], 
  Map[Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, #}, 0.3]] &, {axesLength1 + 0.5, 
     axesLength2 + 0.6, axesLength3 + 0.7} IdentityMatrix[3]]}
labelAxes[{axesLength1_, axesLength2_, axesLength3_}, {o1_String: "x",
    o2_String: "y", o3_String: "z"}, 
  col_: Black] := {col, {Text[
    Style[o1, 20, Italic], {axesLength1 + 0.5, 0, -0.4}], 
   Text[Style[o2, 20, Italic], {0, axesLength2 + 1, -0.4}], 
   Text[Style[o3, 20, Italic], {0.1, 0.5, axesLength3 + 0.6}]}}

ellipsoidXYZ[{a_, b_, c_}, opac1_: 0.6] := {Specularity[White, 10], 
  Blue, EdgeForm[], Opacity[opac1], Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {a, b, c}]}

axes1 = Graphics3D[{arrowAxes[{75, 75, 75}], 
    labelAxes[{80, 80, 80}, {"1", "2", "3"}]}, ImageSize -> Large];
g1 = {Graphics3D[ellipsoidXYZ[{50, 1, 50}]], axes1};
viewpoint = 1.2 {1, 1, 1};
Show[g1, Lighting -> {{"Point", White, 
    viewpoint + {0, 0, 2}}, {"Ambient", RGBColor[0.15, 0.15, 0.15]}}, 
 Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> viewpoint]
```

to create

[image]

I want to crop the white space surrounding the figure.

I use

```
Rasterize[
 Show[g1, Lighting -> {{"Point", White, 
     viewpoint + {0, 0, 2}}, {"Ambient", RGBColor[0.15, 0.15, 0.15]}},
   Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> viewpoint, ImagePadding -> None, 
  Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}], ImageResolution -> 300]
```

[image]

but the labels dissapear.

Also with

```
ImageCrop[
 Rasterize[
  Show[g1, Lighting -> {{"Point", White, 
      viewpoint + {0, 0, 2}}, {"Ambient", 
      RGBColor[0.15, 0.15, 0.15]}}, Boxed -> False, 
   ViewPoint -> viewpoint], ImageResolution -> 300]]
```

the quality of the figure is not the same.

```
In[143]:= $Version

Out[143]= "10.3.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (October 9, 2015)"
```

Comment: What about  choosing a larger `ImageSize` for the rasterized version? Might be the quickest fix...

Comment: the last case looks fine to me with 10.1.  Oddly increasing the resolution to 600 gives a completely black raster.  In any case one thing to try is export to a raster format and read it back in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have often used [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5568/cropping-a-plot-via-a-command) function to crop images.

```
 cropGraphics[g_, x_, y_, w_, h_] := 
   Graphics[Inset[g, {x, y}, {0, 0}], PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
   ImageSize -> {w, h}, ImagePadding -> None, AspectRatio -> Full];

  g2 = Show[g1, 
  Lighting -> {{"Point", White, viewpoint + {0, 0, 2}}, {"Ambient", 
  RGBColor[0.15, 0.15, 0.15]}}, Boxed -> False, 
  ViewPoint -> viewpoint];
```

Playing around a while with the coordinates, you can easily remove all surrounding white space.

```
  res = cropGraphics[g2, -0.08, -0.37, 128, 130];
  Export["image.jpg", res, ImageResolution -> 600]
```

[image]

Note: In the final image I observed some overlap of the axes label `3` with the arrow so I changed the `labelAxes[{80, 80, 84}...` to avoid any overlap.